# power query - how to import csv without losing data

Tags: powerquery, import-csv

I'm importing data from CSV file into Power Query.
The thing is that some of the data comes in a form of "00XYZ" whereas Power Query automatically translates it into "XYZ" even if prohibited from changing the data type to number.
Worth mentioning that I don't experience the same issues when using SSIS for the same purpose.
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: It's really hard to solve a code problem without seeing your code...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to return 00XYZ in all cases

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\TEMP\a.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Regardless of csv use or omission of quotes

"00XYZ","00XYZ","00XYZ"

00XYZ,"00XYZ",00XYZ